# WEBRTC and ASIO (or NAudio)

Tags: webrtc, asio

I would like to add NAudio or specifically ASIO device support to WEBRTC.

1) Can this be done using NAudio?

2) Can this be done using ASIO?

Any advice regarding how to do this?

Also, this is a requirement so a contract to provide this function is available.

Please advise

Best regards

Mark Jarvis

Comment: Have you looked at [Ice links implementation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FM.IceLink.WebRTC.NAudio/)?

Comment: Hi, no I didnt know about icelinks. Big thanks for that!

Comment: All comments suggestions are appreciated